# Cytoscape layout - No such layout cola found

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, cytoscape.js

I am using **Cytoscape on Angular 2 project with Typescript** and wanted to use Cola layout. Hence I added the dependency to my project using npm. Since I am using Angular 2 with Typescript I have added the js module first to the angular-cli.json file then to the index.html file. After that in my NetworkComponent , which is the angular component I am using to display the graph, I am importing the library as follows:

`declare var cola:any;`

Then I am trying to use the layout as follows:

```
   this.cyto = cytoscape({
            container: document.getElementById("graph"),
            elements: this.graph.elements,
            style: res.json()
            });
    this.cyto.layout({name: "cola"});
```

The graph doesn't display and I get the following error in the console:

> Can not apply layout: No such layout 'cola' found; did you include its
>   JS file?

I can use the `concentric` layout and the graph displays but I get the same error for other layout extensions such as `cose-bilkent` and `springy`.

How can I import cola library and use it as my graph layout? What might be wrong here?

Answer (score 3):

1. Install `cytoscape-cola`:

   ```
   npm install cytoscape-cola --save
   ```
2. Import `cytoscape-cola` module:

   ```
   import cola from 'cytoscape-cola';
   ```
3. Use `cola` in component:

   ```
   cytoscape.use(cola);
   ```

then you can call `cola` layout.

Answer (score 0):

It was a simple fix. It turns out I forgot to add a reference to `cola.js` file in `index.html` which is required by `cytoscape-cola.js`. I thought only using `cytoscape-cola.js` was enough, but after adding the *cola* js file it is working properly.